# Is there any way to identify unique_number_identifier for Braintree::AndroidPayCard?

Tags: braintree, android-pay, braintree-rails, braintree-vault

I am using Braintree for payment processing and also I am using Android pay through Braintree. I am saving card details in Braintree for future processing.

While saving card details to Braintree for Android pay users, Braintree did not provide a way to identify that the card already exists or not but if you will use Braintree without Android pay they have an attribute `unique_number_identifier` where I can check that card already exits or not so that I can avoid duplicate card saving.

Is this possible to check Android Pay card exists in Braintree or not?